# Python subprocess batch file quote escaping

Tags: python, batch-file, subprocess, escaping

So it turns out that `subprocess.run` doesn't work so great for batch files when you have double-quotes in your arguments. A batch file with the single statement `echo %*` prints out `\"quoted\"` when called from `subprocess.run(['my.bat', '"quoted"'])`, rather than the expected `"quoted"`. This is apparently [intended behavior](https://bugs.python.org/issue23862).

What seems to be missing is a workaround. How can I avoid having my double-quotes escaped when calling a batch file? Do I have to monkey-patch `subprocess.list2cmdline` or is there a better way?

Comment: If you are using windows, just compose the entire command as a string yourself. I don't believe it is modified if passed as a string rather than a list of strings. This is not necessarily true with linux however. `run('my.bat "quoted"', *args, **kwargs)`